# How to read everyday a data frame, produced daily, and compare to compare with the previous one

Tags: r

I have a question, hopefully somebody might help me.

Everyday, I create a dataframe (df) which I save in my working directory. This dataframe is saved as a ‘.csv’ file. The name of the file is the date in which that file was created, like this:

```
setwd("~/Documents/daily_data/data_August2021")

library(writexl)
write_xlsx(as.data.frame(df), paste0(Sys.Date(), '.csv'))#To create the file with the current date
```

Then, my intention is to compare this dataframe with the one I created the day before. So, I do this:

```
#Compare with previous day
yesterday <- Sys.Date()-1

library(readxl)

df_yesterday <- read.csv(file.path("~/Documents/daily_data/data_August2021",yesterday,".csv"), 
                 header = TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

Consequently, I have this output as a mistake:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Users/Rafa/Documents/daily_data/data_August2021/2021-08-19/.csv': No such file or directory
```

Basically, it seems my code adds an extra slash (“/”) between the name of the file and the extension of the file.

Any help with this problem?? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that it creates the `/` before the `.csv`

```
file.path("~/Documents/daily_data/data_August2021",yesterday, ".csv")
[1] "~/Documents/daily_data/data_August2021/2021-08-20/.csv"   
                                                      ^
```

We could use `paste`

```
file.path("~/Documents/daily_data/data_August2021",paste0(yesterday, ".csv"))
[1] "~/Documents/daily_data/data_August2021/2021-08-20.csv"
```

---

Or another option is to change the `fsep` to blank (`""`)

```
file.path("~/Documents/daily_data/data_August2021/",yesterday, ".csv", fsep = "")
[1] "~/Documents/daily_data/data_August2021/2021-08-20.csv"
```